# How do I set up Java for Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, installation, ide

I recently downloaded Android Studio and the install instructions say I need a certain version of Java sdk installed. I clicked on the link provided and downloaded the file. After trying to install the the Java file, it said a newer version was already installed. How or where can I find the correct file to use with Android Studio?

Comment: Download the latest JDK here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html
Android Studio should work with the latest version of the JDK.

Comment: That's exactly where I downloaded the file from. I tried to install it and it said a newer version is already installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Most of the times it will be installed to default location `C:\\program files\\Java` (OR) `C:\\program files (X86)\\Java`

2) You may check your computer Environment Variables. [How to set environment variables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html)

3) If none of above options work, just search for `java` (OR) `javac` file in windows search.